# Hardware 'Hardware_id' does not have an associated service using install section 'DriverInstall'

Tags: c++, inf

I am writing my first ever V4 printer driver application.When i tried to build the application,i got error messgae like below,

Error:1296 - Hardware 'V4_Printer_Driver' does not have an associated service using install section 'DriverInstall'.

What should i do to resolve this error?

Here is the code of my INF file,

```
; Copyright (c) 2020 SATO
; INF file for the SATO WS208DT-LAN print driver

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Printer
ClassGuid={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=MyV4PrintDriver.cat
ClassVer=4.0
DriverVer=08/01/2019,1.0.0.0

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTamd64

[Standard.NTamd64]
"V4_Printer_Driver"=DriverInstall, {EE345D56-B825-4BD4-B2AC-B6F8F1D180DF}
"V4_Printer_Driver"=DriverInstall, USBPRINT\En-VisionScripTalk_PE65B
"V4_Printer_Driver"=DriverInstall, USBPRINT\En-VisionScripTalk_PE65B

[DriverInstall]
CopyFiles=DriverFiles


[DriverInstall.NTx64.Services]
Include=MyV4PrintDriver.inf
Needs=DDInstall.Services
;AddService = ,0x2

[DDInstall.Services]  
AddService = ,0x2
;AddService=MyV4PrintDriver_Service,0x00000002,service-install-section


[DriverFiles]
MyV4PrintDriver.gpd
MyV4PrintDriver-manifest.ini
MyV4PrintDriverRenderFilter-PipelineConfig.xml
MyV4PrintDriverRenderFilter.dll

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 66000

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""
;2 = %DiskName%,,,amd64

[SourceDisksFiles]
MyV4PrintDriver.gpd=1
MyV4PrintDriver-manifest.ini=1
MyV4PrintDriverRenderFilter-PipelineConfig.xml=1
MyV4PrintDriverRenderFilter.dll=1


[Strings]
ManufacturerName="SATO" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
DiskName="MyV4PrintDriver Installation Disk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz use the link below for workaround of this issue-
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2c1cbcd-cf97-46a0-9a71-b3760a1e9e12/printer-v4-driver-inf-service-issue?forum=wdk

Seems a version bug though.Upon using the workaround u will get a warning stating it will be fixed in next release.

Hope this helps!!

Regards,
Astha